# PhpSpreadSheet weird output

Tags: php, excel, laravel, spreadsheet

I have a problem with my phpSpreadSheet file.

[Link to PhpSpreadSheet Documentation](http://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)

I made the Workbook and added a bunch of sheets to it with names. When I log the amount of sheets and their names I get the correct returns but when I open the actual file that was generated I only see one sheet. It has the same name as the file and is filled with a bunch of gibberish.

See the output below:

```
PKŠaK1iÑü˜[Content_Types].xmlÍWÝNÃ ½÷)nMK™:§Y·§—ºD}„¯k³°
¿·÷k·©1Yã²%rSÒ”óÓ9áx]WÑ¬+µÊKRZ–j–‘÷·§x@"ç¹’¼Ò               
2²GÆ£‹áÛÆ€‹¬\F              
ïÍ=¥NPs—h               
¿äÚÖÜã«QÃÅœÏ€öÒ´O…V”}ÃAFÃÔ·¥„hÊ­æ5ÊÐuE=²ÁöÉä#ÑÃØhg„S•‚{4N—JþRuž—
¤‹!IKsÙ°Ðƒ‚Îo*p'K9cKWøºJ¶¤{å    ä|QùèqìÛÌ-Tî8½]˜    "Û9®(M—B÷Æ-
OñËW¸•:B_i;ÿÐz~îØ›1©y©ºÁS«£(u²h’“ cƒ”`}ù½ìÚB[8^|¿   
ôwi·Ñ8ÚìÌ±ñé£ˆ«@|\âã&ý@|Üâcˆ»@|°4#¡4*¥RY(ÊB)UJ«²Pj•…
Ò«ì¿ŠÕÜ‚|õOËg¿‚üäÞû í
nô  PKŠaK¶78éK_rels/.rels­’ÍjÃ0€ï{
£{£´…1F^Ê ·2²Ðlå‡$–±½-}ûy‡±ºÒÃŽ–
¥OŸ„vûyÕ;‡Ø‹Ó°.JPìŒØÞµ^ê§Õ¨˜ÈYÅ±†3GØWw»g)åšØõ>ªqQC—’DŒ¦ã‰b!ž]þi$L”ò3

´èÉÔ2nÊòÃoT¦:Z
áh· ê³ç[ØÒ4½áƒ˜·‰]ºÐyNì,Û•¹>¤>£j
-'
VÌ)‡#’÷EF^6ÚÜnô÷´8qK‰ÐHàë>_×„Öÿ¹¢eÆÍ<â‡„áUdøvÁÅ"        
TŸPKŠaK|5}×P+xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels½–ÉjÃ0†ï}                
¡{#µÄÎ¥rmÓöx!¶d$uÉÛWm „¡‡0'1côÏÇ>´Þ|½øDç;kr “D          
4¥­:Óäò}÷ò¸”Âm*Ý[ƒ¹< —›âaýŠ½ñŽo»Ñ‹b|.ÛÆ'¥|Ùâ ýÄŽhâ—ÚºA‡XºFºÜëUš$så.3dq•)¶U.Ý¶)v‡ÿ“mëº+ñÙ–špc„òáÐG~±Ó®ÁËc=‰9RÝŸÞs|ˆwñ<ý¯<6bÈîº‚V;¬Þ‚‹?ør—m               
fzO˜/ëö¾EgSë5äffÌ0)3g†É(˜3Ì”‚Y2ÃÌ(˜3Ìœ‚„™fAÒ3Í’¤I™iV$MÆ-¾„Äa÷0)bà61*n)cà¶1:n)dà62JN¹•¤“Sn'ÃIÊêê_üPKŠaKÌäC2ídocProps/app.xml”ÁnÚ@†ï}Š•U"lPU!º8"†*‡„"AÂy³Û+–]kw° Ç>OŸªOÒµ)ŽiR»êmvæÓ¯G3Co;I                
0Vh5ñýÀ# ¸Ž…J'ÞãúKoä‹LÅLjïÖ»    ßÑ¥Ñ9`‰SPvâeˆùØ÷-Ï`Çlß••«$Úìº§I}$‚ÃLóýúÃ øäÃAÅ÷òZÐ;)Žü_ÑXóÒŸ}Zs§ÒižKÁºO†‚mu‚d~à ©ß,R'´¾7a@ýæ“®8“9á0aÒõ_ôXÙ³%Æ†´Àqµ!V|s]zä™Y(íL¼‚Áz'ìô¨b™[4áF›­ÍÐR¿NVa“mÆâc8U„‹.I¿vââKkì×dÉ¾ay0jz®\x         
—óC.™ªšvá³Ž¦R’[ãç/eŽ¢€6b¡UoÅ${–­XÄRmÊA¼r~¿îÄb€ümê¾ôäF'ÞslõÝÊÌ„-]ÇíTó­à¹Hš¬Póm'i‹NÓíE':Ÿ.w€£UúìRVõè™T¨v¸2I®Ü&Êþ5y/ñ3ùùý|‚Nëi†]fÜm#·Šüîõ«¥:oÇûé]ÎÔ±q."mrmª‘§þ¹LÜ¤P                
ÔÑ½P[û˜¯õÌ              
ÝùV\&é*cbw^ê[R'è[9#K>Ê˜J!>3¯åe{:]ïp0ìAÙ·FŽú/‡:üPKŠaK>»ëÕqdocProps/core.xml¥’QKÃ0…ßý%¯Ò%­ £tTö¤ 8Ñ×˜\·¸6 ÉµÿÞ4ÝºÍíM(”ÓsúåÞCÊÛŸ¦N¾ÁyeôŒdFÐÂH¥—3òº˜§S’xäZòÚh˜‘<¹­.Jaa<;cÁ¡Ÿö…°3²B´¥^¬ á~:˜ŸÆ5ƒtKj¹Xó%Ðœ±kÚrÉ‘Ó˜Ú‘H¶H)F¤Ý¸:¤ PC=Í&Ýg\ãÏþƒd£°³p6º3ÇôWc°mÛI{£aþŒ¾?=¾ÄUS¥ûªª”¢8W½êµ6­Nî]Ò¯ï±æŸBãŸ          
ä]w?”Û5È$ŒWËìœ·«û‡ÅœT9ËnR6M³é"Ë‹ðäì’åcýG=µÙžô?ìŽ»@…5„Õâ[&/6œ)ý              
cƒÝ%xá”Åp«h}Úo>¾@à`Ž"t´†®5Nú*6¶WýM              
û-ëë:ºÅÕ/PKŠaKs‘{Y³¦xl/theme/theme1.xmlíYOoÛ6¿ïSº·²lÉu‚:EìØëÖ¦              
·C´DK¬)Q é¤¾                
íqÀ€aÝ°Ë€Ýv¶h]ºO“­ÃÖý               
{úc‹Šé6iSlCëƒ-’¿÷ŸïñQ¾|å^ÌÐ!’ò¤k9"‰Ïš„]ëÖhx¡c!©p`ÆÒµæDZW¶>¸Œ7UDb‚€<‘›¸kEJ¥›¶-}˜Æò"OIk.b¬`(B;øØÆÌn6m;Æ4±P‚càzs2¡>A£Œ¥µµ`>`ð•(™MøLø¹D"ÇS'û‘sÙgbÖµ@NÀFäž²ÃRÁB×jäËÞºl/‰˜ZC«Ñ                
óOIWÓfN'Âñ’Ðº—v–ü›ÿUÜ`0èœ%¿€},uV°î°ãô<5Pñ¸Ê»ßðn¯ño­à7z½ž·QÃ·*¼»‚ï4Úîv³†w+¼·ªo»ßo×ð^…o¯à‡—6ÚnŸƒ"F“é              
:‹ç22KÈ„³«FxàÅ¨P¶¶»             
úD­Ûk1¾ËÅyp±¢   Ró”L°¸>ŽÇ‚âLÞ$X[)¦|¹2•ÉBÒ4U]ëãCFTO|ñô1zñôÑñý'Ç÷9~ðàøþÏÂ«8   uÂçßñ÷·Ÿ¢¿÷üáWf¼Ôñ¿ÿôÙo¿~i*øìëG<yôì›Ïÿüá¡¾-ðX‡hL$ºAŽÐ>Á6ƒ2g£E˜Ö(pHp ¢ðÆ3®GêÎ»- ˜€ÎîÖt=ˆÄLQðZ×€»œ³Fs®e²tsfIh.f:nãC“ìþ‰Ðf)ìdjbÙHMÍ=ÑÆ!IˆBÙŸb »CiÍ¯»Ô\ò‰Bw(êajtÉˆŽ•™è*!.sluÍ7»·Q3ûrXGBB`fbIXÍâ™Â±Qc3y«È¤äÁ\ø5‡K‘   ãh)M47Å¼¦î5•Èö]6ëH¡èÔ„¼Ž9×‘;|Úpœu¦I¤c?’SØ¢íqeT‚×3$Cp²6Ü·)QgKë[4ŒÌ$[™    SJ^ÏÇ9›`’”õ½V©cš¼¬l3
uû}Ù^À·ác§(ÖëpÿÃ½ƒgÉ¬x_¡ßWèw±B¯Ëåó¯ËU)¶õ^;g¯m¼'”±5gäºÌ‹¸ó‚!LæƒœhÙç§<–âj¸Pàü ®>¡*:ˆp         
bœ\B(KÖ¡D)—p»°ÖòÎ¯¨lÎç¼Å½ÐXíò ˜né÷Í%›|J]P+cpZa­Ko&Ì)€§”æxfiÞK¥Ùš7!oÎ^&8íf!6             
f$Èü^0X„åÜC$#2FŽÑ§uJ·u^í5MÚFëÍ¤&Hº8w8ï¢ÔX‰’½šŽ,©Ðhå5=ù8íZè¹à1NŸÌJfaÒµ|UšòÊd>i°y[:µ×D¤Bª,£‚*_Z¼ŽI*ý›ž›ùá|°_W‹VÇùµ°O†–L&ÄWkfªa¹ÆgŠˆƒ(8Bc6ûôv‹ÝP   GEs1¡n¹ñê™_fÁÉ×>ev`–F¸¬I-ö<^ê4õì5º¿¦)­s4Å{wMÉv.4¸­ ¿zA 0Êöh×âBEªPQ( qÈe^Ò"S ±ìv¦+9¬êVÁ£(ra¤öiˆ…J§"AÈž*í|3§©Ÿ¯FeYª+ÓâwL  eÙÛÎì·P´¨&¥#rÜÉ Ù¦ì‡Ãÿpçã6^§=¨¹géE\­èkGÁÆ›©pÆ£¶i¶¸éú¨Máš‚²/(ÜTø¬êoG|¢–%‚x¡S¦ßrr:w4ã2Vo·ªBÐi¼ýæSsvk³·ãlÏàkïå®¶WSÔÖ.2ùhåÏ,>¾²wà~4cJïîÁ¥´¿øøØéÖ?PKŠaK]á‚D^xl/sharedStrings.xml…“MOÃ0†ïü    
+w–±Ã„PÛ    HÛàlZo–&!v§ñï   L\ÚLíçu^(ÅâØY8Pdã]©®&Säjß·+Õfýxy­€]ƒÖ;*Õ±ZT³@*u\ªV$ÜhÍuKòÄr‰l}ìPRwšC$l¸%’ÎêÙt:×§ wæ³§¥ï”j6WUÁ¦*¤ÚD[h©       
ýžR/Ñ7}-`š!yÃhÐåÈ2Ù             
5€2$O÷´ÅÞæÈ             
-~X’»˜Ö0L®ZÄÈXÿ×WÞF1µ%H«±tÙüjßgóïdv­ŒíbÜ±   !7=ÅÂ@ÇÚNþÑ—Óˆ¯÷`é@6ØÛf|ESSÞó„²VËÔ„ó¥ÏwÆý²3(P¬Évôê‘A’„Fhí-Ä4žëÏØž$!ú­‘¡B§R}PKŠaKâ_œÞùh          
xl/styles.xml…”Ën0†÷}               
Ëû†Ã‘Rµ5‘ºhT5TêÖÀV|Aöp              
yúÚ˜ÃE‰6Ìü>?’ûQ             
rc¹V)oN”€ªtÍU›Ò?Eþù+%™ª™Ð               
R:¥÷Ù§Äâ$à¹@âw¶g•[í             
X0 ^T6¥bE¶ê@2{£{Pn¥ÑF2t©i#ëžaµõ$)¢óéô%’Œ+š%j¹DK*=(Lé‰FYÒhµ)1                
B–”äÂÄRÂw±EÃ_`'!Vî]æõ×Ç±Ï*-´!¦-Sšç§ùò²brA<2ÁKÃ½…ç›ump!Ö¾Î4YÒ3D0*w   Yâbêak          
uT·†MñùÖcÛÇ}“áò ò¸°uí¨ë~óÍµ]jS»o¿74HþÁeÑùB<ûïý·9”Ž              
    ßèGíí%Þ‹kèøK0!ñØ=-°ßbÇæ-ò¸Õû|Âú^L¹ç%dOƒ,Áäó‘ÛÕ8À–=ÌŒ-ÿ.x«$L–°kJ:mø«ÃûÓÐ‚Ãõãƒ¼òR©µ¤aÄßÎSå¨ÿë'¦´aÂºù°áê¥Ð9_5oÎØ,­æÌVüYUâOfJŸü«¹6VÓÊäêË³›ãH!+Ý$‡]jhØ °X¥”nñO¨ù ¿ÑkÕ/~Ñ¸TÍñV:S´ý#²ÿPKŠaKXÌ          
¯Üxl/workbook.xml•ßR1Æïû™\tt¦¸»ˆÔÅQÄÖ¥N±zvlÆl²“„?zÙçéSõIzD#Sn²'Ùß—œ/g'§‹RhÃ•LirS2S9—“”þº»¬µ)1–Éœ    %!¥O`èi÷ÓÉ\éÇ‘RùŽ©X†k•zÔMJ“ÒÂÚªE&+ dæ@U qe¬tÉ,†zdXn         
[Š¨Ç­¨d\¾(tôÿh¨ñ˜gp¡²i  Ò.E4f1%SðÊÐîÉ˜¸_fIXU            
X‰ç]J3¶ŸsyJª9¼›ÐÓê|Ê…šq“FÝ×Ìo5AŸ`)uWpóð²à^rã=‡¹y{ß…„e–ÏàŽRZK(aS«.¹° /˜…oZM+o<.¹6vèŒI)^JÉ%/ù³;F¦PóïJóg%-ÃL+!<å<„[˜×ÌÜòìÝ‹–~:‡RÚŠQpÆ              
qÁíSJý³—Fäá/i5éÓî/*ÁäÒi·®\å^_w8>è«¼átBæLr®±¢B¢Í„7í#t@­uh dmÈÃL>’€<Z'{x4Ù1Ã³ý€ld{™T!Ø                
ÀãuðÚåw«U>ÍlxÎ£Jâ-¾làÚ!—¬sÜ8[òMäqHÖw™ºÆ#ôá:½"È@‘¡UÙcˆ†5“4v¡=e,îŽß|È‡”4wñý³jäïè°”’ÖVúA+9Ù(VTr´}{˜0i7LO\Ÿ{S++ioUð‰“½þ"ûä³°_ÉßßHò%ŽCµ°Ü’ã]v<Ÿ6dÃª«Ç;rÁÿ                
r ÉKM„"a    Ö}  F«’Ã˜KÈ]ç48)sÍ_þG}|ƒ.§ÔuÉeÜSe%À÷f×"§Bôpö‡¼VÌ7F·ËªßvÿPKŠaKÂ+ÿ™xl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlTÉrÛ0½÷+4¼×rÚtåLšÖMgÒI&Ks¦EÈbM*    ÙM¿¾ µ:é¡'Äðhyö»2Éœ×h3q2›‹lŽJÛm&î×¯?ŠÄ“´J´‰'ðâlõjy@·ó%%L°ðµÌù°vàÁíAÐúL”Dõ"M}^B%ýk°|R «$±ë¶©ç©"SeÒ7óùû´’Úv÷?X:‡Ï˜7XjIIÜ“/uíÅj3Ü¸Õ2ÚÂK|SUÒ=}ƒn]ôÀ­Þ–€tµL‡8¥™<¨”8(2q~²87â…~b'$7w` 'P™`Mƒ\Ä]8üÖB¾ÄÃW§ÕWÃR‘k oñpæ’eág    u0qä
É%öpÆ„8àWWÎXmÈ1µûÂÖQ2n\A!Cœçº^Og§"é¤¹‚=˜Û ÉüãªÖ7ýY’Le‘º             
£Ÿ‰BÏ               
áæ'ã~ð}V:#Ò¾dèè†¦©ìs”+!myà^\lÑ\¼|ªÁq?»ñ@±´ÏZôˆ¡}ƒ+Ìw Ž«õèÆ†eC¸Ö†À               
P­÷H÷rcà9Ûƒ5/ùXÓÚiK×uàd;I< wAé89!Hná»t[n51PðÉ|öA$®}âhÖÑz'’              
aÕ{eœ¶à½                
:#õNÇË‰š:©%Ëw§ÿ@\tš×-nY&º™              
,M8Ÿóðšîq˜±ÎÔŠÊn½Ú´ë˜/Qº(À1åµR_ö`ÇÇèÖÚyšŒgzÔTòæ÷û#ÞÚ€uBt8¯½RíFñfLl6Ûì-ÜÛ<ív¸>u‚=L"”6„yÑ‚Ž½©ìÕÕ_PKŠaKç—Ÿ“³xl/worksheets/sheet2.xmlTMsÓ0½ó+4º»P“‰Ó)-¡Ì”i§ô¬Xk[DÖIN(¿ž•ü§åÀÉ»o¥·»O»^žý®5Ûu             
MÆOf)g`r”Ê”|X¿ýÄ™óÂH¡Ñ@ÆŸÁñ³Õ›åíÖUžÁÂ5"§`cÁÝ q¯¼oIâò                
jáfØ€¡H¶ž\[&Žî™j¼KÓI-”éö8°(T—˜·5ß‘XÐÂSO®Rã«eÌpkWK/6¨Ñ2[n2¾^§ó|žÎy²Zbëµ2pk™këZØçÏ qO¢ð¸Seå@§“‘Q*JôcŠŒŸŸ,Îã‰xà‡‚½›ØŒòßƒ†ÜƒÌ8©„Ü nCð[¹             
÷_­’×T              
‰èmx‡{ªýŠ£uqä               
É}vpZ‡èÂ¯¾œCµ!ÇÔ                
[G1©q   …hµ§<WÐ÷z:;å¬—æv ï‚&é1FUlhúRx‘Œš£ï+Œ~Æ¡5„›Ÿ„»Ñw9aîCG¯0Ômm^¢TÙR†FñÕÁýÇÁ«ç,õ³=$Iëá%C‡1topùäqµí¡aÑz\+íÁŽP£vèÄFÃK¶G£_ó‘¦UÆß4q´Yy’þòˆÜ¥ãä„K¢„ïÂ–Ô*ÓPP$Í9³ÝGÛc­œmÐ{¬¯ŠÓ¼÷AgôƒÓóR¢¶a ùîÕˆë‚VÑ"ÆýËx?Sá…ñ”†§PþÇëý'%}Õ¯W—vó1©Š,QÞHùeæðC`­¬ó“Q¢LOÊWôOöGhUš€õBô8­½”ÝFÑfLl2»ì<Ø4íf<>u‚=^˜:E(m¼räEg¼tìM wüß®þPKŠaKç—Ÿ“³xl/worksheets/sheet3.xmlTMsÓ0½ó+4º»P“‰Ó)-¡Ì”i§ô¬Xk[DÖIN(¿ž•ü§åÀÉ»o¥·»O»^žý®5Ûu         
MÆOf)g`r”Ê”|X¿ýÄ™óÂH¡Ñ@ÆŸÁñ³Õ›åíÖUžÁÂ5"§`cÁÝ q¯¼oIâò                
jáfØ€¡H¶ž\[&Žî™j¼KÓI-”éö8°(T—˜·5ß‘XÐÂSO®Rã«eÌpkWK/6¨Ñ2[n2¾^§ó|žÎy²Zbëµ2pk™këZØçÏ qO¢ð¸Seå@§“‘Q*JôcŠŒŸŸ,Îã‰xà‡‚½›ØŒòßƒ†ÜƒÌ8©„Ü nCð[¹             
÷_­’×T              
‰èmx‡{ªýŠ£uqä               
É}vpZ‡èÂ¯¾œCµ!ÇÔ                
[G1©q   …hµ§<WÐ÷z:;å¬—æv ï‚&é1FUlhúRx‘Œš£ï+Œ~Æ¡5„›Ÿ„»Ñw9aîCG¯0Ômm^¢TÙR†FñÕÁýÇÁ«ç,õ³=$Iëá%C‡1topùäqµí¡aÑz\+íÁŽP£vèÄFÃK¶G£_ó‘¦UÆß4q´Yy’þòˆÜ¥ãä„K¢„ïÂ–Ô*ÓPP$Í9³ÝGÛc­œmÐ{¬¯ŠÓ¼÷AgôƒÓóR¢¶a ùîÕˆë‚VÑ"ÆýËx?Sá…ñ”†§PþÇëý'%}Õ¯W—vó1©Š,QÞHùeæðC`­¬ó“Q¢LOÊWôOöGhUš€õBô8­½”ÝFÑfLl2»ì<Ø4íf<>u‚=^˜:E(m¼räEg¼tìM wüß®þPKŠaK{ç¹’³xl/worksheets/sheet4.xmlTMsÓ0½ó+4º»Ð“‰Ó)-¦Ì”i§ô¬Xk[DÖIN¿ž•ü‘¤åÀÉ»o¥·»O»^œÿn4Û€u            
MÆOf)g`             
”ÊTzÌß~âÌya¤Ðh ã;pü|ùf±E»v5€gD0w­((ØZp`7Àh\ÆkïÛy’¸¢†F¸¶`(R¢m„'×V‰£;BF¦F'ïÒôCÒe†¹ý,KUÀ]Æ÷$´ðÔ“«Uëør3ÜÙåÂ‹Õ%j´ÌV«ŒçyYŠ³4åÉr×ÊÀe®kawŸAã–Dá#p¯ªÚ€N'£T”6èÇ,”¿8™_ÄñÀ[w`3Êÿ                
2ã¤vr…¸Áo=äjÜ~µJÞP5$¢·ôà=n©ökŒ,ÔAÄ‘+$ôÙÀ%hj ¿†röÕ†‡öXXÅ¤Æ%”¢Óžò\ÃÐëéì”³AšØ€¾š¤ÇU°±é+áE2iŽ~¨0ú/…vÔ®~î&ß`„U¸Gú7½ÂPwy‰Re{HÅW{ô¯w-Xêg½H’ÖÃK†=bèßà‹5ÈãjÚ}Ã¢ó˜+íÁNP«6èÅJÃK¶'£_ó‘¦­UÆß¶q´Yµ’áò„<¥ãä„K¢‚ïÂVÔ*ÓPR$}äÌöOmm´Î8[¡÷ØŒ^§-xïƒÎèGgà¥D]ËZAò=¨?×­¢EŒû—ña¦Ââ´m¬Tþ§üg%}=¬WŸ6ù˜Te    –(o¥ü²³Œ1+ëüÁ(Q¦gåkú'Œû#´ªLÀ!œÖ^Ê~£h3l2ûì=<Ú4íf:~è{ºpè”¡´éÊ‘éÒ±w(¹ÓÿvùPKŠaKç—Ÿ“³xl/worksheets/sheet5.xmlTMsÓ0½ó+4º»P“‰Ó)-¡Ì”i§ô¬Xk[DÖIN(¿ž•ü§åÀÉ»o¥·»O»^žý®5Ûu          
MÆOf)g`r”Ê”|X¿ýÄ™óÂH¡Ñ@ÆŸÁñ³Õ›åíÖUžÁÂ5"§`cÁÝ q¯¼oIâò                
jáfØ€¡H¶ž\[&Žî™j¼KÓI-”éö8°(T—˜·5ß‘XÐÂSO®Rã«eÌpkWK/6¨Ñ2[n2¾^§ó|žÎy²Zbëµ2pk™këZØçÏ qO¢ð¸Seå@§“‘Q*JôcŠŒŸŸ,Îã‰xà‡‚½›ØŒòßƒ†ÜƒÌ8©„Ü nCð[¹             
÷_­’×T              
‰èmx‡{ªýŠ£uqä               
É}vpZ‡èÂ¯¾œCµ!ÇÔ                
[G1©q   …hµ§<WÐ÷z:;å¬—æv ï‚&é1FUlhúRx‘Œš£ï+Œ~Æ¡5„›Ÿ„»Ñw9aîCG¯0Ômm^¢TÙR†FñÕÁýÇÁ«ç,õ³=$Iëá%C‡1topùäqµí¡aÑz\+íÁŽP£vèÄFÃK¶G£_ó‘¦UÆß4q´Yy’þòˆÜ¥ãä„K¢„ïÂ–Ô*ÓPP$Í9³ÝGÛc­œmÐ{¬¯ŠÓ¼÷AgôƒÓóR¢¶a ùîÕˆë‚VÑ"ÆýËx?Sá…ñ”†§PþÇëý'%}Õ¯W—vó1©Š,QÞHùeæðC`­¬ó“Q¢LOÊWôOöGhUš€õBô8­½”ÝFÑfLl2»ì<Ø4íf<>u‚=^˜:E(m¼räEg¼tìM wüß®þPKŠaKç—Ÿ“³xl/worksheets/sheet6.xmlTMsÓ0½ó+4º»P“‰Ó)-¡Ì”i§ô¬Xk[DÖIN(¿ž•ü§åÀÉ»o¥·»O»^žý®5Ûu         
MÆOf)g`r”Ê”|X¿ýÄ™óÂH¡Ñ@ÆŸÁñ³Õ›åíÖUžÁÂ5"§`cÁÝ q¯¼oIâò                
jáfØ€¡H¶ž\[&Žî™j¼KÓI-”éö8°(T—˜·5ß‘XÐÂSO®Rã«eÌpkWK/6¨Ñ2[n2¾^§ó|žÎy²Zbëµ2pk™këZØçÏ qO¢ð¸Seå@§“‘Q*JôcŠŒŸŸ,Îã‰xà‡‚½›ØŒòßƒ†ÜƒÌ8©„Ü nCð[¹             
÷_­’×T              
‰èmx‡{ªýŠ£uqä               
É}vpZ‡èÂ¯¾œCµ!ÇÔ                
[G1©q   …hµ§<WÐ÷z:;å¬—æv ï‚&é1FUlhúRx‘Œš£ï+Œ~Æ¡5„›Ÿ„»Ñw9aîCG¯0Ômm^¢TÙR†FñÕÁýÇÁ«ç,õ³=$Iëá%C‡1topùäqµí¡aÑz\+íÁŽP£vèÄFÃK¶G£_ó‘¦UÆß4q´Yy’þòˆÜ¥ãä„K¢„ïÂ–Ô*ÓPP$Í9³ÝGÛc­œmÐ{¬¯ŠÓ¼÷AgôƒÓóR¢¶a ùîÕˆë‚VÑ"ÆýËx?Sá…ñ”†§PþÇëý'%}Õ¯W—vó1©Š,QÞHùeæðC`­¬ó“Q¢LOÊWôOöGhUš€õBô8­½”ÝFÑfLl2»ì<Ø4íf<>u‚=^˜:E(m¼räEg¼tìM wüß®þPKŠaK­ÎAÄxl/worksheets/sheet7.xml–ËvÛ †÷}            
öäÜÜúXÎi.ŽÓ:Mšk›–F5°Ýôé;èfAºèÊÌ|03üˆÁã“ß6 4“"&ƒ½ˆ ™2±ŒÉãÃôýhCEJ¹“WÐädòn¼•j¥s`€‘.i‚°T Am€X§Ð1É)Ga¨“              
ª÷d I&UA            
šjj\CÓ*RÁÃý(:ÊDa¤þ'†Ì2–À¹LÖSQÀ©Á=éœ•šLÆU†[5º8“\ª@-1™N£a2Œ†$œŒåÚp&àVz]T½ž—[…´Ž;¶Ìuàì°‹˜2Lkõd1ù4½T3ª  O¶º70ÿ=pH¤1Aµ­)W^Õ.Ëí¥bé«AZCí¼“[¬}†‚áÙ:0pË&§ø³3àÜÖ€~5åìªµ9úã¶°i%&n<…Œ®¹Á<3höz¸wH‚Fš9l€ßYM"×‡UY_»ésjèd¬ä6Pµ|%µ_Ã`´Œ%'Ök+Äðöh6“hn°®¤a§}6pÙYŸí»ì¼Ï\vÑg‡.›öÙ‘Ë.ûìØe³>ºìªÏ>¸ìsŸ}tÙgïž0szÊ\;Ð“æ«=mnè‰së@Ooôä¹s §Ï½=è)ôè|žBOôzv §Ðwz           
ýp §Ð‹w             
…xÚÛVßˆ¦eHÓ\ÙÊŽIF¹Æ.?Ñ¯;[' ¨brç©›ž½âo|’¯á{ñªî\L`o~3±öþcâìµ…|µ)ö~„ÚëD¨›Ò\&+HÝjµT»                
Óµ‘SÆ               
¨ÎU²4tÁÁö(øÛxØpJÅ„¹)«^,w]³YÜyî­ÒU+µ‹è®©ZâV’hoHU÷¼jldYŽH°ÆÈ¢µòªýZëÀê,Mk4q1ÑºJŠòÝ³?P5@©¾LÕƒ“¦ÉÚ¦Üò»iÆÌƒìšnc?³ÔäÍ{S§Vù‚”e(y“¦»ÃhÁ”)mzŸfzf&ÇG²}P(gKa}ßÁ4­Ÿüx{cÖÙkw;Æö/ºé}ÃŽ»}#³¥uK«2ºE®ÕÍîÈä/PKŠaKç—Ÿ“³xl/worksheets/sheet8.xmlTMsÓ0½ó+4º»P“‰Ó)-¡Ì”i§ô¬Xk[DÖIN(¿ž•ü§åÀÉ»o¥·»O»^žý®5Ûu               
MÆOf)g`r”Ê”|X¿ýÄ™óÂH¡Ñ@ÆŸÁñ³Õ›åíÖUžÁÂ5"§`cÁÝ q¯¼oIâò                
jáfØ€¡H¶ž\[&Žî™j¼KÓI-”éö8°(T—˜·5ß‘XÐÂSO®Rã«eÌpkWK/6¨Ñ2[n2¾^§ó|žÎy²Zbëµ2pk™këZØçÏ qO¢ð¸Seå@§“‘Q*JôcŠŒŸŸ,Îã‰xà‡‚½›ØŒòßƒ†ÜƒÌ8©„Ü nCð[¹             
÷_­’×T              
‰èmx‡{ªýŠ£uqä               
É}vpZ‡èÂ¯¾œCµ!ÇÔ                
[G1©q   …hµ§<WÐ÷z:;å¬—æv ï‚&é1FUlhúRx‘Œš£ï+Œ~Æ¡5„›Ÿ„»Ñw9aîCG¯0Ômm^¢TÙR†FñÕÁýÇÁ«ç,õ³=$Iëá%C‡1topùäqµí¡aÑz\+íÁŽP£vèÄFÃK¶G£_ó‘¦UÆß4q´Yy’þòˆÜ¥ãä„K¢„ïÂ–Ô*ÓPP$Í9³ÝGÛc­œmÐ{¬¯ŠÓ¼÷AgôƒÓóR¢¶a ùîÕˆë‚VÑ"ÆýËx?Sá…ñ”†§PþÇëý'%}Õ¯W—vó1©Š,QÞHùeæðC`­¬ó“Q¢LOÊWôOöGhUš€õBô8­½”ÝFÑfLl2»ì<Ø4íf<>u‚=^˜:E(m¼räEg¼tìM wüß®þPKŠaK{ç¹’³xl/worksheets/sheet9.xmlTMsÓ0½ó+4º»Ð“‰Ó)-¦Ì”i§ô¬Xk[DÖIN¿ž•ü‘¤åÀÉ»o¥·»O»^œÿn4Û€u            
MÆOf)g`             
”ÊTzÌß~âÌya¤Ðh ã;pü|ùf±E»v5€gD0w­((ØZp`7Àh\ÆkïÛy’¸¢†F¸¶`(R¢m„'×V‰£;BF¦F'ïÒôCÒe†¹ý,KUÀ]Æ÷$´ðÔ“«Uëør3ÜÙåÂ‹Õ%j´ÌV«ŒçyYŠ³4åÉr×ÊÀe®kawŸAã–Dá#p¯ªÚ€N'£T”6èÇ,”¿8™_ÄñÀ[w`3Êÿ                
2ã¤vr…¸Áo=äjÜ~µJÞP5$¢·ôà=n©ökŒ,ÔAÄ‘+$ôÙÀ%hj ¿†röÕ†‡öXXÅ¤Æ%”¢Óžò\ÃÐëéì”³AšØ€¾š¤ÇU°±é+áE2iŽ~¨0ú/…vÔ®~î&ß`„U¸Gú7½ÂPwy‰Re{HÅW{ô¯w-Xêg½H’ÖÃK†=bèßà‹5ÈãjÚ}Ã¢ó˜+íÁNP«6èÅJÃK¶'£_ó‘¦­UÆß¶q´Yµ’áò„<¥ãä„K¢‚ïÂVÔ*ÓPR$}äÌöOmm´Î8[¡÷ØŒ^§-xïƒÎèGgà¥D]ËZAò=¨?×­¢EŒû—ña¦Ââ´m¬Tþ§üg%}=¬WŸ6ù˜Te    –(o¥ü²³Œ1+ëüÁ(Q¦gåkú'Œû#´ªLÀ!œÖ^Ê~£h3l2ûì=<Ú4íf:~è{ºpè”¡´éÊ‘éÒ±w(¹ÓÿvùPKŠaK{ç¹’³xl/worksheets/sheet10.xmlTMsÓ0½ó+4º»Ð“‰Ó)-¦Ì”i§ô¬Xk[DÖIN¿ž•ü‘¤åÀÉ»o¥·»O»^œÿn4Û€u            
MÆOf)g`             
”ÊTzÌß~âÌya¤Ðh ã;pü|ùf±E»v5€gD0w­((ØZp`7Àh\ÆkïÛy’¸¢†F¸¶`(R¢m„'×V‰£;BF¦F'ïÒôCÒe†¹ý,KUÀ]Æ÷$´ðÔ“«Uëør3ÜÙåÂ‹Õ%j´ÌV«ŒçyYŠ³4åÉr×ÊÀe®kawŸAã–Dá#p¯ªÚ€N'£T”6èÇ,”¿8™_ÄñÀ[w`3Êÿ                
2ã¤vr…¸Áo=äjÜ~µJÞP5$¢·ôà=n©ökŒ,ÔAÄ‘+$ôÙÀ%hj ¿†röÕ†‡öXXÅ¤Æ%”¢Óžò\ÃÐëéì”³AšØ€¾š¤ÇU°±é+áE2iŽ~¨0ú/…vÔ®~î&ß`„U¸Gú7½ÂPwy‰Re{HÅW{ô¯w-Xêg½H’ÖÃK†=bèßà‹5ÈãjÚ}Ã¢ó˜+íÁNP«6èÅJÃK¶'£_ó‘¦­UÆß¶q´Yµ’áò„<¥ãä„K¢‚ïÂVÔ*ÓPR$}äÌöOmm´Î8[¡÷ØŒ^§-xïƒÎèGgà¥D]ËZAò=¨?×­¢EŒû—ña¦Ââ´m¬Tþ§üg%}=¬WŸ6ù˜Te    –(o¥ü²³Œ1+ëüÁ(Q¦gåkú'Œû#´ªLÀ!œÖ^Ê~£h3l2ûì=<Ú4íf:~è{ºpè”¡´éÊ‘éÒ±w(¹ÓÿvùPKŠaK!?h‡‘³xl/worksheets/sheet11.xmlTÉrÛ0½÷+8¼×rÚtåLšVMgÒI&Ks¦EHbM*IÙM¿¾ µ:é¡¾x$€G@ë³ßµf{°N¡IùÉbÉ˜¥2eÊî³×9s^)4Hù8~¶yµ> Ý¹         
À3"X¹FätØXp`÷Àh\Ê+ï›U’¸¼‚Z¸6`è¤@[O®-G1BF¦Z'o–Ë÷I-”éVö8°(TŸ1ok0¾#± …§ž\¥Ç7ë˜áÆnÖ^l/P£e¶Ü¦<ËŠbI?žlÖØz­ÜXæÚºöéh<(|nUYùÐídd”ŠÒý˜…"åç'«óx#^ø¡ààf6£üw !÷ SNj!·ˆ»pø­ƒ\…‡¯VÉ+ª†Dô¶…¼ÅÕ~I‚Ñƒ…:ˆ8r…ä‚þöpZ‡(àW_ÎTmÈ1·‡Â²(&5.¡­ö”çú^O§œõÒ\ÁômÐdyŒQUšþ,¼HFÍÑ÷F?å…ÐŽÂíOÂÝè»Œ°             
'¤{ãÐÑu[›ç(U6AÊÐ(¾¸Ø¡ÿ¸xùÔ€¥~vÓ$i=<gèÐ#†î               
®0ß<®Ö¡­ÇLiv„µG/¶ž³=ý’4m¬2þº‰£ÍÊiHúà¹JÇÉ    A¢„ïÂ–Ô*ÓPÐÉrñ3Û=q´=6ÑzÇÙ½Çzðª8mÁ{tF?8=/%jÖ’ïNý¸.h-bÜ¿”÷3XèpNÛÆ         
åïqœ±ÞTÒWýzui³˜IU`‰òZÊ/{0Óc™²ÎÏF‰2=*_Ñ7aØ¡UiÖÑã´öRvE›1³Éì²wð`Ó´›ñúÜ ö0wŠPÚräEg:öæ;~o7PKŠaK!?h‡‘³xl/worksheets/sheet12.xmlTÉrÛ0½÷+8¼×rÚtåLšVMgÒI&Ks¦EHbM*IÙM¿¾ µ:é¡¾x$€G@ë³ßµf{°N¡IùÉbÉ˜¥2eÊî³×9s^)4Hù8~¶yµ> Ý¹          
À3"X¹FätØXp`÷Àh\Ê+ï›U’¸¼‚Z¸6`è¤@[O®-G1BF¦Z'o–Ë÷I-”éVö8°(TŸ1ok0¾#± …§ž\¥Ç7ë˜áÆnÖ^l/P£e¶Ü¦<ËŠbI?žlÖØz­ÜXæÚºöéh<(|nUYùÐídd”ŠÒý˜…"åç'«óx#^ø¡ààf6£üw !÷ SNj!·ˆ»pø­ƒ\…‡¯VÉ+ª†Dô¶…¼ÅÕ~I‚Ñƒ…:ˆ8r…ä‚þöpZ‡(àW_ÎTmÈ1·‡Â²(&5.¡­ö”çú^O§œõÒ\ÁômÐdyŒQUšþ,¼HFÍÑ÷F?å…ÐŽÂíOÂÝè»Œ°             
'¤{ãÐÑu[›ç(U6AÊÐ(¾¸Ø¡ÿ¸xùÔ€¥~vÓ$i=<gèÐ#†î               
®0ß<®Ö¡­ÇLiv„µG/¶ž³=ý’4m¬2þº‰£ÍÊiHúà¹JÇÉ    A¢„ïÂ–Ô*ÓPÐÉrñ3Û=q´=6ÑzÇÙ½Çzðª8mÁ{tF?8=/%jÖ’ïNý¸.h-bÜ¿”÷3XèpNÛÆ         
åïqœ±ÞTÒWýzui³˜IU`‰òZÊ/{0Óc™²ÎÏF‰2=*_Ñ7aØ¡UiÖÑã´öRvE›1³Éì²wð`Ó´›ñúÜ ö0wŠPÚräEg:öæ;~o7PKŠaK!?h‡‘³xl/worksheets/sheet13.xmlTÉrÛ0½÷+8¼×rÚtåLšVMgÒI&Ks¦EHbM*IÙM¿¾ µ:é¡¾x$€G@ë³ßµf{°N¡IùÉbÉ˜¥2eÊî³×9s^)4Hù8~¶yµ> Ý¹          
À3"X¹FätØXp`÷Àh\Ê+ï›U’¸¼‚Z¸6`è¤@[O®-G1BF¦Z'o–Ë÷I-”éVö8°(TŸ1ok0¾#± …§ž\¥Ç7ë˜áÆnÖ^l/P£e¶Ü¦<ËŠbI?žlÖØz­ÜXæÚºöéh<(|nUYùÐídd”ŠÒý˜…"åç'«óx#^ø¡ààf6£üw !÷ SNj!·ˆ»pø­ƒ\…‡¯VÉ+ª†Dô¶…¼ÅÕ~I‚Ñƒ…:ˆ8r…ä‚þöpZ‡(àW_ÎTmÈ1·‡Â²(&5.¡­ö”çú^O§œõÒ\ÁômÐdyŒQUšþ,¼HFÍÑ÷F?å…ÐŽÂíOÂÝè»Œ°             
'¤{ãÐÑu[›ç(U6AÊÐ(¾¸Ø¡ÿ¸xùÔ€¥~vÓ$i=<gèÐ#†î               
®0ß<®Ö¡­ÇLiv„µG/¶ž³=ý’4m¬2þº‰£ÍÊiHúà¹JÇÉ    A¢„ïÂ–Ô*ÓPÐÉrñ3Û=q´=6ÑzÇÙ½Çzðª8mÁ{tF?8=/%jÖ’ïNý¸.h-bÜ¿”÷3XèpNÛÆ         
åïqœ±ÞTÒWýzui³˜IU`‰òZÊ/{0Óc™²ÎÏF‰2=*_Ñ7aØ¡UiÖÑã´öRvE›1³Éì²wð`Ó´›ñúÜ ö0wŠPÚräEg:öæ;~o7PKŠaK!?h‡‘³xl/worksheets/sheet14.xmlTÉrÛ0½÷+8¼×rÚtåLšVMgÒI&Ks¦EHbM*IÙM¿¾ µ:é¡¾x$€G@ë³ßµf{°N¡IùÉbÉ˜¥2eÊî³×9s^)4Hù8~¶yµ> Ý¹          
À3"X¹FätØXp`÷Àh\Ê+ï›U’¸¼‚Z¸6`è¤@[O®-G1BF¦Z'o–Ë÷I-”éVö8°(TŸ1ok0¾#± …§ž\¥Ç7ë˜áÆnÖ^l/P£e¶Ü¦<ËŠbI?žlÖØz­ÜXæÚºöéh<(|nUYùÐídd”ŠÒý˜…"åç'«óx#^ø¡ààf6£üw !÷ SNj!·ˆ»pø­ƒ\…‡¯VÉ+ª†Dô¶…¼ÅÕ~I‚Ñƒ…:ˆ8r…ä‚þöpZ‡(àW_ÎTmÈ1·‡Â²(&5.¡­ö”çú^O§œõÒ\ÁômÐdyŒQUšþ,¼HFÍÑ÷F?å…ÐŽÂíOÂÝè»Œ°             
'¤{ãÐÑu[›ç(U6AÊÐ(¾¸Ø¡ÿ¸xùÔ€¥~vÓ$i=<gèÐ#†î               
®0ß<®Ö¡­ÇLiv„µG/¶ž³=ý’4m¬2þº‰£ÍÊiHúà¹JÇÉ    A¢„ïÂ–Ô*ÓPÐÉrñ3Û=q´=6ÑzÇÙ½Çzðª8mÁ{tF?8=/%jÖ’ïNý¸.h-bÜ¿”÷3XèpNÛÆ         
åïqœ±ÞTÒWýzui³˜IU`‰òZÊ/{0Óc™²ÎÏF‰2=*_Ñ7aØ¡UiÖÑã´öRvE›1³Éì²wð`Ó´›ñúÜ ö0wŠPÚräEg:öæ;~o7PKŠaK!?h‡‘³xl/worksheets/sheet15.xmlTÉrÛ0½÷+8¼×rÚtåLšVMgÒI&Ks¦EHbM*IÙM¿¾ µ:é¡¾x$€G@ë³ßµf{°N¡IùÉbÉ˜¥2eÊî³×9s^)4Hù8~¶yµ> Ý¹          
À3"X¹FätØXp`÷Àh\Ê+ï›U’¸¼‚Z¸6`è¤@[O®-G1BF¦Z'o–Ë÷I-”éVö8°(TŸ1ok0¾#± …§ž\¥Ç7ë˜áÆnÖ^l/P£e¶Ü¦<ËŠbI?žlÖØz­ÜXæÚºöéh<(|nUYùÐídd”ŠÒý˜…"åç'«óx#^ø¡ààf6£üw !÷ SNj!·ˆ»pø­ƒ\…‡¯VÉ+ª†Dô¶…¼ÅÕ~I‚Ñƒ…:ˆ8r…ä‚þöpZ‡(àW_ÎTmÈ1·‡Â²(&5.¡­ö”çú^O§œõÒ\ÁômÐdyŒQUšþ,¼HFÍÑ÷F?å…ÐŽÂíOÂÝè»Œ°             
'¤{ãÐÑu[›ç(U6AÊÐ(¾¸Ø¡ÿ¸xùÔ€¥~vÓ$i=<gèÐ#†î               
®0ß<®Ö¡­ÇLiv„µG/¶ž³=ý’4m¬2þº‰£ÍÊiHúà¹JÇÉ    A¢„ïÂ–Ô*ÓPÐÉrñ3Û=q´=6ÑzÇÙ½Çzðª8mÁ{tF?8=/%jÖ’ïNý¸.h-bÜ¿”÷3XèpNÛÆ         
åïqœ±ÞTÒWýzui³˜IU`‰òZÊ/{0Óc™²ÎÏF‰2=*_Ñ7aØ¡UiÖÑã´öRvE›1³Éì²wð`Ó´›ñúÜ ö0wŠPÚräEg:öæ;~o7PKŠaK!?h‡‘³xl/worksheets/sheet16.xmlTÉrÛ0½÷+8¼×rÚtåLšVMgÒI&Ks¦EHbM*IÙM¿¾ µ:é¡¾x$€G@ë³ßµf{°N¡IùÉbÉ˜¥2eÊî³×9s^)4Hù8~¶yµ> Ý¹          
À3"X¹FätØXp`÷Àh\Ê+ï›U’¸¼‚Z¸6`è¤@[O®-G1BF¦Z'o–Ë÷I-”éVö8°(TŸ1ok0¾#± …§ž\¥Ç7ë˜áÆnÖ^l/P£e¶Ü¦<ËŠbI?žlÖØz­ÜXæÚºöéh<(|nUYùÐídd”ŠÒý˜…"åç'«óx#^ø¡ààf6£üw !÷ SNj!·ˆ»pø­ƒ\…‡¯VÉ+ª†Dô¶…¼ÅÕ~I‚Ñƒ…:ˆ8r…ä‚þöpZ‡(àW_ÎTmÈ1·‡Â²(&5.¡­ö”çú^O§œõÒ\ÁômÐdyŒQUšþ,¼HFÍÑ÷F?å…ÐŽÂíOÂÝè»Œ°             
'¤{ãÐÑu[›ç(U6AÊÐ(¾¸Ø¡ÿ¸xùÔ€¥~vÓ$i=<gèÐ#†î               
®0ß<®Ö¡­ÇLiv„µG/¶ž³=ý’4m¬2þº‰£ÍÊiHúà¹JÇÉ    A¢„ïÂ–Ô*ÓPÐÉrñ3Û=q´=6ÑzÇÙ½Çzðª8mÁ{tF?8=/%jÖ’ïNý¸.h-bÜ¿”÷3XèpNÛÆ         
åïqœ±ÞTÒWýzui³˜IU`‰òZÊ/{0Óc™²ÎÏF‰2=*_Ñ7aØ¡UiÖÑã´öRvE›1³Éì²wð`Ó´›ñúÜ ö0wŠPÚräEg:öæ;~o7PKŠaK!?h‡‘³xl/worksheets/sheet17.xmlTÉrÛ0½÷+8¼×rÚtåLšVMgÒI&Ks¦EHbM*IÙM¿¾ µ:é¡¾x$€G@ë³ßµf{°N¡IùÉbÉ˜¥2eÊî³×9s^)4Hù8~¶yµ> Ý¹          
À3"X¹FätØXp`÷Àh\Ê+ï›U’¸¼‚Z¸6`è¤@[O®-G1BF¦Z'o–Ë÷I-”éVö8°(TŸ1ok0¾#± …§ž\¥Ç7ë˜áÆnÖ^l/P£e¶Ü¦<ËŠbI?žlÖØz­ÜXæÚºöéh<(|nUYùÐídd”ŠÒý˜…"åç'«óx#^ø¡ààf6£üw !÷ SNj!·ˆ»pø­ƒ\…‡¯VÉ+ª†Dô¶…¼ÅÕ~I‚Ñƒ…:ˆ8r…ä‚þöpZ‡(àW_ÎTmÈ1·‡Â²(&5.¡­ö”çú^O§œõÒ\ÁômÐdyŒQUšþ,¼HFÍÑ÷F?å…ÐŽÂíOÂÝè»Œ°             
'¤{ãÐÑu[›ç(U6AÊÐ(¾¸Ø¡ÿ¸xùÔ€¥~vÓ$i=<gèÐ#†î               
®0ß<®Ö¡­ÇLiv„µG/¶ž³=ý’4m¬2þº‰£ÍÊiHúà¹JÇÉ    A¢„ïÂ–Ô*ÓPÐÉrñ3Û=q´=6ÑzÇÙ½Çzðª8mÁ{tF?8=/%jÖ’ïNý¸.h-bÜ¿”÷3XèpNÛÆ         
åïqœ±ÞTÒWýzui³˜IU`‰òZÊ/{0Óc™²ÎÏF‰2=*_Ñ7aØ¡UiÖÑã´öRvE›1³Éì²wð`Ó´›ñúÜ ö0wŠPÚräEg:öæ;~o7PKŠaK!?h‡‘³xl/worksheets/sheet18.xmlTÉrÛ0½÷+8¼×rÚtåLšVMgÒI&Ks¦EHbM*IÙM¿¾ µ:é¡¾x$€G@ë³ßµf{°N¡IùÉbÉ˜¥2eÊî³×9s^)4Hù8~¶yµ> Ý¹          
À3"X¹FätØXp`÷Àh\Ê+ï›U’¸¼‚Z¸6`è¤@[O®-G1BF¦Z'o–Ë÷I-”éVö8°(TŸ1ok0¾#± …§ž\¥Ç7ë˜áÆnÖ^l/P£e¶Ü¦<ËŠbI?žlÖØz­ÜXæÚºöéh<(|nUYùÐídd”ŠÒý˜…"åç'«óx#^ø¡ààf6£üw !÷ SNj!·ˆ»pø­ƒ\…‡¯VÉ+ª†Dô¶…¼ÅÕ~I‚Ñƒ…:ˆ8r…ä‚þöpZ‡(àW_ÎTmÈ1·‡Â²(&5.¡­ö”çú^O§œõÒ\ÁômÐdyŒQUšþ,¼HFÍÑ÷F?å…ÐŽÂíOÂÝè»Œ°             
'¤{ãÐÑu[›ç(U6AÊÐ(¾¸Ø¡ÿ¸xùÔ€¥~vÓ$i=<gèÐ#†î               
®0ß<®Ö¡­ÇLiv„µG/¶ž³=ý’4m¬2þº‰£ÍÊiHúà¹JÇÉ    A¢„ïÂ–Ô*ÓPÐÉrñ3Û=q´=6ÑzÇÙ½Çzðª8mÁ{tF?8=/%jÖ’ïNý¸.h-bÜ¿”÷3XèpNÛÆ         
åïqœ±ÞTÒWýzui³˜IU`‰òZÊ/{0Óc™²ÎÏF‰2=*_Ñ7aØ¡UiÖÑã´öRvE›1³Éì²wð`Ó´›ñúÜ ö0wŠPÚräEg:öæ;~o7PKŠaKÍKR"x#xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x#xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet2.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x#xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet3.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x#xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet4.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x#xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet5.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x#xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet6.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x#xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet7.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x#xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet8.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x#xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet9.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x$xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet10.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x$xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet11.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x$xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet12.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x$xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet13.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x$xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet14.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x$xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet15.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x$xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet16.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x$xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet17.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaKÍKR"x$xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet18.xml.relsMŒ1!{_A¶÷@cÌq×ù£Øp+a!,1ú{)-'“™yýä¤ÞÔ$¶p˜(bW¶ÈÞÂã~ÝŸAIGÞ0&_X—Ý|£„}4b5&,Bïõ¢µ¸@e*•x˜giûÀæuE÷BOúhÌI·ÿèåPKŠaK1iÑü˜¶[Content_Types].xmlPKŠaK¶78éK¶É_rels/.relsPKŠaK|5}×P+¶Ûxl/_rels/workbook.xml.relsPKŠaKÌäC2í¶cdocProps/app.xmlPKŠaK>»ëÕq¶ÃdocProps/core.xmlPKŠaKs‘{Y³¦¶cxl/theme/theme1.xmlPKŠaK]á‚D^¶Gxl/sharedStrings.xmlPKŠaKâ_œÞùh          
¶½xl/styles.xmlPKŠaKXÌ              
¯Ü¶áxl/workbook.xmlPKŠaKÂ+ÿ™¶½xl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlPKŠaKç—Ÿ“³¶rxl/worksheets/sheet2.xmlPKŠaKç—Ÿ“³¶;xl/worksheets/sheet3.xmlPKŠaK{ç¹’³¶xl/worksheets/sheet4.xmlPKŠaKç—Ÿ“³¶Ìxl/worksheets/sheet5.xmlPKŠaKç—Ÿ“³¶•"xl/worksheets/sheet6.xmlPKŠaK­ÎAÄ¶^%xl/worksheets/sheet7.xmlPKŠaKç—Ÿ“³¶Õ(xl/worksheets/sheet8.xmlPKŠaK{ç¹’³¶ž+xl/worksheets/sheet9.xmlPKŠaK{ç¹’³¶f.xl/worksheets/sheet10.xmlPKŠaK!?h‡‘³¶/1xl/worksheets/sheet11.xmlPKŠaK!?h‡‘³¶÷3xl/worksheets/sheet12.xmlPKŠaK!?h‡‘³¶¿6xl/worksheets/sheet13.xmlPKŠaK!?h‡‘³¶‡9xl/worksheets/sheet14.xmlPKŠaK!?h‡‘³¶O<xl/worksheets/sheet15.xmlPKŠaK!?h‡‘³¶?xl/worksheets/sheet16.xmlPKŠaK!?h‡‘³¶ßAxl/worksheets/sheet17.xmlPKŠaK!?h‡‘³¶§Dxl/worksheets/sheet18.xmlPKŠaKÍKR"x#¶oGxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x#¶(Hxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet2.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x#¶áHxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet3.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x#¶šIxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet4.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x#¶SJxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet5.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x#¶Kxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet6.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x#¶ÅKxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet7.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x#¶~Lxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet8.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x#¶7Mxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet9.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x$¶ðMxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet10.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x$¶ªNxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet11.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x$¶dOxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet12.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x$¶Pxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet13.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x$¶ØPxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet14.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x$¶’Qxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet15.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x$¶LRxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet16.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x$¶Sxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet17.xml.relsPKŠaKÍKR"x$¶ÀSxl/worksheets/_rels/sheet18.xml.relsPK--êzT<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' property='stylesheet' href='//localhost:8000/_debugbar/assets/stylesheets?v=1500969470'><script type='text/javascript' src='//localhost:8000/_debugbar/assets/javascript?v=1500969470'></script><script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

Here is the code I use to build the file:

```
 $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

    $infoTab                    = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.info_tab'));
    $allBrands                  = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.all_brands'));
    $activeBrands               = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.active_brands'));
    $nonSalableBrands           = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.non_salable_brands'));
    $tooLowMarginBrands         = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.too_low_margin_brands', ['amount' => 5]));
    $tooLowMarginPercentBrands  = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.too_low_margin_percent_brands', ['amount' => 15]));

    $categoriesBasic = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.basic_categories'));
    $categoriesDeep  = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.deep_categories'));

    $liveProducts                = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.live_products'));
    $activeProducts              = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.active_products'));
    $disabledProducts            = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.disabled_products'));
    $nonSalableProducts          = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.non_salable_products'));
    $tooLowMarginProducts        = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.too_low_margin_products', ['amount' => 5]));
    $tooLowMarginPercentProducts = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.too_low_margin_percent_products', ['amount' => 15]));

    $noStockProducts        = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.no_stock_products'));
    $noCostPriceProducts    = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.no_cost_price_products'));
    $noEanProducts          = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.no_ean_code_products'));
    $wrongEanProducts       = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.wrong_ean_code_products'));
    $negativeMarginProducts = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.negative_margin_products'));
    $tooLowPriceProducts    = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.too_low_price_products'));
    $noWeightProducts       = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.no_weight_products'));
    $neverSalableProducts   = new Worksheet($spreadsheet, trans('labels.backend.report.never_salable_products'));

    $spreadsheet->addSheet($infoTab, 0);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($allBrands, 1);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($activeBrands, 2);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($nonSalableBrands, 3);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($categoriesBasic, 4);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($categoriesDeep, 5);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($liveProducts, 6);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($activeProducts, 7);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($disabledProducts, 8);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($nonSalableProducts, 9);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($noStockProducts, 10);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($noCostPriceProducts, 11);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($noEanProducts, 12);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($wrongEanProducts, 13);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($negativeMarginProducts, 14);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($tooLowPriceProducts, 15);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($noWeightProducts, 16);
    $spreadsheet->addSheet($neverSalableProducts, 17);

$productHeaders = [
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.url'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.product_id'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.variant_id'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.created_at'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.is_default'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.is_salable'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.brand'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.short_title'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.variant_title'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.article_code'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.ean'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.sku'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.weight'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.vat_rate'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.shipping_costs_excl'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.shipping_costs_incl'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.stock_level'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.stock_sold'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.price_excl'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.price_incl'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.cost_price_excl'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.margin_excl'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.margin_percent'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.roas_target_percent'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.total_revenue_excl'),
        trans('strings.backend.dashboard.report.product.total_profit_excl'),
    ];

$liveProducts->fromArray($productHeaders);
    $liveProducts->fromArray((array) $products, null, 'A2');

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx");
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Product-Report.xls"');
 $writer->save("php://output");
```

I hope someone can help me figure out why this keeps appearing instead of my actual data.

Comment: May be a typo in the header name `Content-Type`, check if you are getting the headers correctly inspecting it in your browser.

Comment: @Asur I'm not getting a response call so I can't check it but I checked some more links online and they all use the same headers as I do. So I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Okay I take it back, the header was wrong.

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx");
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Product-Report.xlsx"');
 $writer->save("php://output");

Is the correct way.

Comment: I thought so, sorry I couldn't give you more specific info but I don't know what file extensions you are managing

Answer (score 0):

in my case I fixed the same problem add this line: **ob_end_clean();**

```php
ob_end_clean();
$Excel_writer->save('php://output');
```

Is important that add before **$Excel_writer->save** line